# jQuery Datatable access row data ( render parameter ) on jQuery click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have created link in datatable as:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "columnDefs": [ {
        "targets": 1,
        "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
            return '<a href="'+data+'" data-id="'+full.id+'">Download</a>';
         }
      } ]
} );
```

I can access `id` on clicking `<a>` tag using jQuery `click` event, but I have several fields to access. And I don't want to use `data-` attribute to access each field.

How can I access row object **i.e.(`full`)** , in jQuery event ?

What I have tried is:

```
"render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
    alert(full);
    return '<a href="'+data+'" data-full="'+full+'">Download</a>';
}
```

In jQuery event `alert( $(this).data('full') );`  I can see only `[Object object]`.
I have tried to convert it to **String** but no success.

Comment: Instead of `alert` use `console.log($(this).data('full'))`

Comment: ok, I will try and let u know

Comment: @OffirPe'er still printing `[object Object]`

Comment: Its ajax call, will take time to create fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`row().data()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().data()) API method to get data for any given row.

For example:

```
$('#example').on('click', 'tbody a', function(){
   var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
   var data = table.row($tr).data();
   console.log(data);
});
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/xfc6yetq/2/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: I already tried this it only gives me visible column values, but one of my requirement is to get `hidden` field also

Comment: @shantaram_t, It's not true, it will return the array/object that was received from the server including data fields that are not shown in the table.

Comment: then I will give another try , and let u know

Comment: Thanks it worked now, problem  I tried to access it using `array` notation `[ ]`

Answer (score 0):

Try [jquery .data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) to set / get data

```
$(your_component).data("full", full)
```

or

```
JSON.stringify(full) // convert json to string
```

Comment: I just want to `get` it also tried `JSON.stringify( $(this).data(`full`) )` , but no success

Comment: To get data, you should use `$(this).data('full')`, the param is not an object. You can try `alert(JSON.stringify($(this).data('full')))` to check your object is right. If you are using Chrome, developer tools for debugging is better.

Comment: Change `return '<a href="'+data+'" data-full="'+full+'">Download</a>';` to `return '<a href="'+data+'" data-full="'+JSON.stringify(full)+'">Download</a>';`

Comment: This will do trick, but I have large data, only need to access 5-6 attributes, then It will be better if I use **`data-`** for these fields

Comment: `JSON.stringify(full)` will be long `String`, can't I pass it as an `Obect` ?

Comment: How about to save your object in global variable or localStorage?

Comment: Also, I changed the codepen example, see div id=3, maybe that is your answer.

Comment: `How about to save your object in global variable or localStorage?` -> I want to access values on `click` event (particular row only),

Comment: `JSON.stringify(full)` will be long String, will be visible if I **Inspect element**